# Castle Windsor - Automatic Transaction Management

Tags: castle-windsor

Are there any simple examples on how to use Castle Windsor's Automatic Transaction Management?  The [documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/%28S%28nppam045y0sdncmbazr1ob55%29%29/Windsor.ATM-Facility.ashx) seems to be lacking some information.  I see there are facilities for nHibernate, ActiveRecord, etc....  However, I'm looking for a simple implementation just to understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://code.google.com/p/mausch/source/detail?r=215) a simple sample app that uses ASP.NET MVC + Castle Automatic Transaction Facility + NHibernate facility.